# Is this sentence right ? 用两个语言把自己介绍

Tags: simplified-characters

I'm making a video which I speak a few words about myself in two languages. I want to have a Chinese title for it.

> 1- 用 (使用/通过) 两个语言把自己介绍
>
> 2- 用(使用/通过) 两个语言把自己介绍
>
> 3- 用 (使用/通过) 两个语言来介绍自己
>
> 4- 用(使用/通过)两个语言介绍自己

Which one is correct ? or any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: (我)(使)用两种语言(来)介绍(下)自己. Words in the brackets can be omitted to keep concise for a title.

Comment: I'll use 3. No. 4 is fine too, except it sounds mandatory. IMO, the grammar of no. 1 & 2 are incorrect, but are quite often spoken by the foreigners.

Comment: 谢谢朋友们 ! "今天我想用两种语言把自己介绍给你们。"这个句子对不对 ?

Answer (score 3):

The correct classifier for 语言 is not 个, but 种

The following are grammatically correct

用两种语言介绍自己

以两种语言介绍自己

两种语言的自我介紹

> I want to have a Chinese title for it

双语 (bilingual) is less wordy and more literary than 两种语言 (two languages) which is more colloquial

As a title, a noun phrase feels more formal than a verb phrase

Depend on your preference you can consider:

**以双语介绍自己** = Introduce Yourself Bilingually (verb phrase)

or

**双语自我介绍** = Bilingual Self-introduction (noun phrase)

Comment: it was so useful. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The Chinese characters should be 3 and 4。
Adding "来" to the third sentence makes people feel closer。
More like the words of a human being than the words printed on paper。
By the way
The word "两个语言" in the title should not be"个 ", but "钟". The language's quantifier is" 种"
That's not a mistake：）This is Chinese

Comment: Please, at the very least, proofread your answer (钟).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!